# Using a InterSystem Caché database in SharePoint?

Tags: bcs, database

I have searched for any kind of database compatible with SharePoint and at this point I haven't found anything.

I've searched on google and msdn. Google gave me this only thread about my question : [SharePoint with Intersystems Cache on the back end?](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/sharepoint-with-intersystems-cache-on-the-back-end/)  Kinda worrying... and msdn doesn't seem to give what are compatible databases with SharePoint or i don't know how to search on it.

Anyway my question is: Is it possible to use InterSystem Caché database in SharePoint?

I'm trying to find out if this could work with BCS (I don't really have enrivonment to test it, i've been asked to search for informations about this).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you're attempting to solve -- You want to cache responses from an external system (that you're connecting to via BCS?) so that SharePoint can serve them quickly/efficiently? SharePoint already does without having to add any external services...

Comment: @John-M apparently you don't know what's Caché. http://www.intersystems.com/our-products/cache/cache-overview/ Here a link for you.

Comment: You're right, I didn't understand it was a specific product; since it is a specific product your question is probably better asked through the product support site instead of here.